# Creating classes in pimcore

Tags: mysql, nginx, pimcore

I'm new to the whole pimcore thing. I am trying to play around and create classes. The issue is, I am not able to create more than 1 class, and in the database it is nameless, so when I try to create another class, it also tries to store it in the database with no name, which ends up showing an SQL error saying that there is a duplicate entry. Any ideas what the reason behind this could be?

I installed pimcore on an nginx server, I am trying to create classes by choosing Settings->Objects->Classes and then "Add Class", creating the first class was ok, I entered a name for the class and it was successfully added, however the name field in the corresponding database entry is empty, as in empty string ' '. So, when I try to add another class and pimcore attempts to store it in the table "classes", it returns an error saying that it would be a duplicate entry since they both are nameless, i.e. the name entered isn't added. The following error is what I managed to find using developer tools, could be helpful.

[WARN] Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server
minified_javascript_core_f5757da….js?_dc=3708:5684 Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: 
**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function hasChilds() on null in **/var/www/html/pimproject/pimcore/modules/admin/controllers/DocumentController.php** on line **59**

```
at new Ext.Error (http://192.10.0.0/pimcore/static6/js/lib/ext/ext-all.js?_dc=3708:22:27054)
at Function.Ext.apply.raise (http://192.10.0.10/pimcore/static6/js/lib/ext/ext-all.js?_dc=3708:22:27447)
at Object.Ext.raise (http://192.10.0.10/pimcore/static6/js/lib/ext/ext-all.js?_dc=3708:22:27594)
at Object.Ext.JSON.me.decode (http://192.10.0.10/pimcore/static6/js/lib/ext/ext-all.js?_dc=3708:22:385102)
at Ext.define.onProxyLoad (http://192.10.0.10/website/var/tmp/minified_javascript_core_f5757da9fa29d5bf13e6aa5058eff9f7.js?_dc=3708:5641:28)
at Ext.cmd.derive.triggerCallbacks (http://192.10.0.10/pimcore/static6/js/lib/ext/ext-all.js?_dc=3708:22:594533)
at Ext.cmd.derive.setCompleted (http://192.10.0.10/pimcore/static6/js/lib/ext/ext-all.js?_dc=3708:22:594231)
at Ext.cmd.derive.setException (http://192.10.0.10/pimcore/static6/js/lib/ext/ext-all.js?_dc=3708:22:594444)
at Ext.cmd.derive.process (http://192.10.0.10/pimcore/static6/js/lib/ext/ext-all.js?_dc=3708:22:593638)
at Ext.cmd.derive.processResponse (http://192.10.0.10/pimcore/static6/js/lib/ext/ext-all.js?_dc=3708:22:648303)
```

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome downvoter. To provide more insight, I installed pimcore on an nginx server, I am trying to create classes by choosing Settings->Objects->Classes and then "Add Class", creating the first class was ok, I entered a name for the class and it was successfully added, however the name field in the corresponding database entry is empty, as in empty string ' '. So, when I try to add another class and pimcore attempts to store it in the table "classes", it returns an error saying that it would be a duplicate entry since they both are nameless, i.e the name entered isnt added

Comment: I think you need to ask a more specific question, maybe add your comment above to the question

Comment: should I elaborate more? or do you think this would be sufficient? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Newb what pimcore version (and build number) are you running exactly?

Comment: according to the website the version I have is 4.0.0

Comment: does nginx have permissions to write to website/var/classes ? just for test if you try 'chmod -R 777 website/var/classes' when in project root folder, or can you check if file website/var/classes/definition_Classname.php is created?

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall Pimcore.
It can be some composer or submodules error.

I strongly recommend for the first installation to run Demo project https://github.com/pimcore/demo not Skeleton, especially if you are using Docker. Later, when you will get the feeling of Pimcore, feel free to install Skeleton or any other project.

Pimcore is stable working for years. If you had some problems before -- nowadays, it is stable.